# Derivative of sum

Tags: derivatives

I'm reading a book on neural networks, and there's the demonstration for the slope of the error function.

I don't understand the last step, where it differentiates the expression inside the sigmoid function.

[Last step and final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEbkE.png)

Why is $\frac{\partial}{\partial w_{jk}}\sum_j w_{jk} \cdot o_j$ = $o_j$ ?

All variables are vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed index $j_o$ and $k_o$, note that 
$$
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} w_{j_ok_o}} 
 w_{jk} ·o_j 
=
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{rcl}
1\cdot o_{j_o} & \mbox{if} & j_o=j \mbox{ and } k_o=k\\
0 & \mbox{if} & j_o\neq j \mbox{ or } k_o\neq k \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then we have 
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} w_{j_ok_o}} 
%\left\lgroup 
\sum_j w_{jk} ·o_j
%\right\rgroup
&=
\sum_j
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} w_{j_ok_o}} 
 w_{jk} ·o_{j}
=
o_{j_o} 
\end{align}

Comment: That was very clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an abuse of notations in your book because $j$ is used as a variable and as an index for the summation.

It would be more correct to write

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial w_{jk}} \sum_{j'}w_{j'k}\cdot o_{j'}$$

Among all these $j'$ only one of them is equal to $j$. Therefore the sum is

$$\sum_{j' \neq j}w_{j'k}\cdot o_{j'} + w_{jk}\cdot o_j$$

When you derive this with respect to $w_{jk}$ the derivative of the first sum is $0$.

Comment: You need to change this to partial derivatives.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand where is j' coming from. I forgot to mention that the variables are all vectors (including w_jk). Edited original question.

Comment: @NicodeOry when you write $\sum_j u_j$ it is the same as $\sum_p u_p$ or $\sum_{j'} u_{j'}$. But since $j$ is already used for saying with respect to which vector you want to derive you should not use it to index your sum.